# Cherry pick only commits that touch a particular file

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

What is a concise way to request "cherry pick from another branch only the commits that touch a particular file"?  i.e. the command `git log ..other-branch afile` gives a list of unmerged commits in other-branch that touch "afile"; how can I request that this same set of commits be replayed on the current branch?

Comment: Can't you just merge in the most recent commit which touched the relevant file?

Comment: @watson I can't do that, because that would also merge in lots of commits that I don't want to merge in.  I only want to pull in the changes from the small subset of commits that touch the one file.

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, you're either going to have to grab just the one file, everything from the latest commit that changed that file, or some grab-bag of files from the latest commit that you think are relevant.

Comment: Do you also want **only** the changes from that commit that actually touch the relevant file?

Comment: Applying the entire commit is fine.  Selecting the list of commits to apply is the important thing.  (In fact, copy-pasting sha1's on the command line as arguments to `git cherry-pick` would get the job done.  But there's got to be a better way.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git cherry-pick $(git log --reverse --pretty=format:"%H" filename)`

Should do the trick. `git log --reverse --pretty=format:"%H" filename` basically gives you a newline separated list of SHA's of all commits that modified `filename` in reverse order so the commits merge in the correct order. We then feed the list to git cherry-pick.

`git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse HEAD -- filename)`is another version of the above command provided by Magnus Bäck.

Comment: "and then sed replaces all \n's (newlines) with spaces" -- You don't need that. As long as IFS has its default value, newline and spaces behave the same way in an unquoted $(...) expansion.

Comment: I ended up using a construct like that - I'm still wondering if there's a way to do this that doesn't involve bash command interpolation.  I guess it's not a common enough need...

Comment: Well never tried it without the sed part and don't have a test case so I didn't want to post something I didn't test before.

Comment: @gcbenison: It doesn't strike me as terribly common, but more importantly since it's trivially done with existing building blocks I don't see why it should be a special command (or done via special-purpose options to existing commands).

Comment: For scripting purposes prefer `git rev-list` over `git log`. Also, you probably want `--reverse` to apply the cherry-picks in the correct order, no? We'd end up with this: `git cherry-pick $(git rev-list --reverse HEAD -- filename)`

Comment: As I said this was a command I used before so I didn't really go over it. Edited the post to add `--reverse` and your version with `rev-list`